# Use own depth/coordinate data with 'marmap' for bathymetry analyses

Tags: r

I have over 111,000 longitude and latitude points with depths associated with each coordinate. The data is in the format Longitude, Latitude, and Depth. When I load the data into R and convert the data into class bathy using as.bathy R seems to hang. When I check the format using is.bathy R returns FALSE. Can 'marmap' handle such large datasets?

Answer (score 0):

There could be several causes to this behavior; to help you diagnose the problem, could you send me: 
-  your session info (use sessionInfo() ) and tell me what kind of machine you have (e.g. RAM)?
-  your code and the error message that you received? 
- your data, or a subset of it, so I can try to re-create the problem here, on my machine?

cheers, eric